Powerapps - How to create a collection from a dataverse table, adding concatenated columns, without loosing original columns values?
I'm new to powerapps, and I'm having some trouble with a simple task.
I'm trying to make a collection from a dataverse table, adding two columns to this original table: column zone, which will have the value "unassigned", and column Modification, which should have the concatenated value of a few other columns, when they are not blank. Also, my powerapps is in regional language portuguese, keep that in mind.
So, with the following code, I successfully retrieve the first 30 rows of the database, keeping all the original columns and cell values, and with the additional "Zone" column:
ClearCollect(colOligos; 
AddColumns(
FirstN('Teste Oligoss';30);
    Zone;"unassigned"));;

But, if I try to add the code lines for creating the second column, "Modifications", it will simply give me the collection with all original columns, plus the 2 columns I created, where "Zone" and "Modifications" are correctly assembled, the columns I've mentioned (m5, m3, Interno 3, Interno 4, etc) will have the correct original values, but all the other columns that I originally had in the dataverse database, they are there, but they are blank. (The Left function is used to remove the trailing separator (" | ") from the concatenated string.
ClearCollect(colOligos;
AddColumns(
    FirstN( 'Teste Oligoss';30);
    Zone;  "unassigned";
    Modifications; 
    Left(
        Concatenate(
            If(Not IsBlank(m5); m5 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(m3); m3 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank('Interno 3'); 'Interno 3' & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank('Interno 4'); 'Interno 4' & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(I); "dI" & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(Fosforotioato); "*" & " | "; "")
        );
        Len(
            Concatenate(
                If(Not IsBlank(m5); m5 & " | "; "");
                If(Not IsBlank(m3); m3 & " | "; "");
                If(Not IsBlank('Interno 3'); 'Interno 3' & " | "; "");
                If(Not IsBlank('Interno 4'); 'Interno 4' & " | "; "");
                If(Not IsBlank(I); "dI" & " | "; "");
                If(Not IsBlank(Fosforotioato); "*" & " | "; "")
            )
        ) - 3
    )
)
);;

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong... Why adding Zone column worked just fine, and adding a column with data from other columns, gives me a lot of blank columns? How can I fix it?
After many, many many attempts, I realized I could achieve the desired outcome with something like this:
ClearCollect(
colOligos;
AddColumns(
    ShowColumns(
        FirstN('Teste Oligoss'; 30);
        cr870_m5; cr870_m3; cr870_interno3; cr870_interno4; cr870_i; cr870_fosforotioato; cr870_lote; cr870_nt; cr870_purification; cr870_pedido 
        /* Adicione aqui todas as outras colunas que deseja manter */
    );
    Zone; "unassigned";
    Modifications; 
    Left(
        Concatenate(
            If(Not IsBlank( cr870_m5 );cr870_m5 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_m3); cr870_m3 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_interno3); cr870_interno3 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_interno4); cr870_interno4 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_i); "dI" & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_fosforotioato); "*" & " | "; "")
        );
        Len(
            Concatenate(
                If(Not IsBlank( cr870_m5 );cr870_m5 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_m3); cr870_m3 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_interno3); cr870_interno3 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_interno4); cr870_interno4 & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_i); "dI" & " | "; "");
            If(Not IsBlank(cr870_fosforotioato); "*" & " | "; "")
            )
        ) - 3
    )
)
);;

However, there are many inconvenient and many behaviors I can't understand, and certainly better solutions.
For instance:

Using ShowColumns, I have to reference one by one all the columns I want to keep, and they are many (in the example before I used only a few, for the sake of simplicity, but for the real thing I would have to add many more column names;
In this code, using the columns names didn't work anymore. I had to use the entire name of the columns (like cr870_m5 instead of simply m5). Why?
And mainly, why the previous original code didn't work? Why the code worked just fine, - keeping all original columns, when adding only Zone, and cleared all the original columns when adding the concatenated column?

Any insights and tips are appreciated.
